# cannot find (and thus automate grabbing) radio station url embedded in website

Tags: web, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I have been completely unsuccessful at finding the radio station url in a number of websites. Most recently in http://www.rocking.gr/

Can someone provide a manual method so that I can manually find where these elusive urls are located?

I think in this website it is a json webplayer responsive for playing the content.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it differs from site to site, in the one you posted for example the URL is http://stream.radiojar.com/rockingradio, to find it i just opened the browser's developer tools and checked the http resources being grabbed

Comment: hi there, thank you for this. I am a complete noob with json. What if the streaming-url changes? how would I be able to pick it up?

Comment: there is no json in this case, the stream url seems to be embedded in the page, it's really different from case to case, with this website though i don't think you have to worry about changes since the url i have you seems to be static

Comment: arrghh! it is killing me , I am searching through this page and I cannot get that link. where is it hidden ??